# Trying to get data out of "Get" Request

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
let linkID = "ZCN";

$.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=${linkID}&tsyms=USD&api_key=68aca28e5a6aadcc7844a6a8523f55f75beb65f8b40228ab51b585cef8b02fa6`, (res)=>{
console.log(res);
})
```

the output is:

```
{"ZCN":{"USD":0.04801}}
```

My goal is to get the **USD** value (0.04801), so what I have been trying:

```
let linkID = "ZCN";

$.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=${linkID}&tsyms=USD&api_key=68aca28e5a6aadcc7844a6a8523f55f75beb65f8b40228ab51b585cef8b02fa6`, (res)=>{
    console.log(res.linkID.USD)
})
```

And the outcome is undefined...
What should I do?

Comment: `res.[linkID].USD`  That field needs to be queried dynamically.

Comment: jmargolisvt  is right. Just no dot after res: `res[linkID].USD`

Comment: Thank you  Hero Qu

Comment: Added your answer for completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution is

```
let linkID = "ZCN";


$.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=${linkID}&tsyms=USD&api_key=68aca28e5a6aadcc7844a6a8523f55f75beb65f8b40228ab51b585cef8b02fa6`, (res)=>{
    console.log(res[linkID].USD)
});
```

(Note the **removed dot**, therefor **changed notation** in the `console.log` statement)